# Como setar um char em um PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

A minha variável TipoCombustivel é um `char` como setar isso no PreparedStatement ?

```
PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, veiculo.getTipoCombustivel());
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use `ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(veiculo.getTipoCombustivel()));`

Comment: Valeu, deu certo !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exatamente dessa forma, porém é necessário que o tipo passado seja uma String.

Portanto:

```
ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(veiculo.getTipoCombustivel()));
```

Mapeamento de tipos:

```
JDBC Type              Java Type
-------------------------------------------
CHAR                   String
VARCHAR                String
LONGVARCHAR            String
NUMERIC                java.math.BigDecimal
DECIMAL                java.math.BigDecimal
BIT                    boolean
BOOLEAN                boolean
TINYINT                byte
SMALLINT               short
```

Comment: @Jarwin Converta sua variável `char` para `String`. Luiz, se puder atualize sua resposta acrescentando essas informações, para refletir  a atualização na pergunta. Aí ela fica completa. Abraço!